# Cannot seem to replace the native menu with the menu I created, so 2 menus appear

Tags: menus

Helping a friend w/ a navigational menu on a WordPress PHP site -- called it **Primary Menu**.  I'm trying to override the default navigational menu with the jquery-mega-menu I created in the widget area I created.

**Here's the problem:**

I'd like to have the menu in the widget area I created, "**my_mega_menu**", which calls the Primary Menu.  But the inkthemes_nav() function adds the Primary Menu also.  When I comment this out in header.php, it shows only the menu I want it to show, but it breaks the functionality of the menu; the drop-downs don't drop down into the sub-menus.

Does anybody know if it's possible to eliminate the inkthemes_nav native menu, but maintain the functionality of the jquery-mega-menu I created?

[image: Double Menu]

**Here's the code in my header.php:**

```
<div class="menu-bar">
<div id="MainNav">                  
<a href="#" class="mobile_nav closed"><?php _e('Pages Navigation Menu', 'colorway'); 
?><span></span></a>    

<?php inkthemes_nav(); ?>            
<?php /* Widgetized sidebar */
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('my_mega_menu') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>            
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<!--End MenuBar-->
</div>
```

Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer to point me in the proper direction (what I should be looking for, what to do, etc.)!

Answer (score 2):

The Problem here is that you call your function `inkthemes_nav()` and also call the sidebar with the widget for the menu in it `dynamic_sidebar('my_mega_menu')`.

So you have two solutions:

- Skip the Function, just calling it from the Widget inside your sidebar
- Skip the Sidebar, and let the Function handle the Menu

As I suppose you have to use your Menu in a Widget due to the MegaMenu Plugin (please correct me if I am wrong), I'd suggest the first Solution.

You do not have to have an extra Function for your Menu - registering and putting it into the Widget does the Trick for you.

Comment: Hi Fishi.  Thanks for taking the time to respond!  I went into my header.php, and just changed it to this:                          <?php 
inkthemes_nav(); 
?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar('my_mega_menu'); ?> ......

Comment: But if I don't include 
<?php dynamic_sidebar('my_mega_menu'); ?> in the header.php, of course it doesn't show.  If I erase <?php 
inkthemes_nav(); ?>, his theme's native menu, then the drop-downs stop working on the mega_menu.  Yes, I'm using the named plugin.  I'm assuming that's what you meant when you said "skip the function, just calling it from the Widget inside your sidebar -- meaning eliminate the my_mega_menu function from header.php ... Again, I appreciate your time!  Thanks ... will continue to work on it!  His site is currently at http://daydreamshotel.com/wordpress/ ...

Comment: Ooops ... I just put the mega-menu inside the inkthemes_nav() parenthesees, and that just put the native menu underneath the mega_menu ... still tryin'!

Comment: I just used CSS and display:none to get rid of the menu ... I guess that's a better fix, anyway, than messing with the header.php or functions.php.  Thanks again for taking the time to help, fischi!

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you're calling a sidebar. Is your menu within the sidebar, as a widget? Where is your new menu registered? You need to register a menu in `function.php` (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus)) and then call in it your theme

Comment: Hi Got Fever ... yes, I created a sidebar widget in functions.php (have done this with other themes), and placed the widget in the header ... but the results are just that ... http://daydreamshotel.com/wordpress/ ..... if you hover over the top, above the index link, you'll see there's still a menu there ... I just made it blank for a temporary fix.  For whatever reason, when I delete the native menu, the drop-down functions of the widget menu I created stop working .... but with the native menu, the drop downs work fine ...